# Is there nothing wrong with digits in identifier name?

Tags: java, c++, c, syntax, defensive-programming

Since in **C\C++\Java**  -

`int 2a ;  //invalid suffix "a" on integer constant`

Is there nothing wrong with digits in the rest of variant name although it's valid syntax  ?

Like -

```
int num1 ;
int num_1st ;
int num_2nd ;
```

Comment: `int num_1st; int num_2nd;` is better expressed as `int num[2]` which you can use as `num[0]` and `num[1]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never heard of anybody (e.g., any coding standards/guidelines) that had a problem with digits in an identifier. Nonetheless, too many of them *can* indicate that a vector or array might be preferable -- even with only two, your `num_1st` and `num_2nd` might be better as `numbers[2]`.

Answer (score 5):

An *identifier* cannot start with a number. It must start with a letter or an underscore.

Comment: I think he was asking more along the lines of in practice is it bad to have numbers in variable names.  He acknowledged that it can't start with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Variables identifier must start with a letter or an underscore, but the rest of the characters can be letter, underscore or a digit.

You can even decalre a variable:
int _ = 0;

Or if you are familiar with regular expression, it can be patterned as:
"[a-zA-Z_]\w*?\b"

Where the \w*? part is not a must.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is, no there is nothing wrong with numbers in the rest of the identifier name.

Comment: Sure, you **say** there is nothing wrong with numbers in the rest of the identifier name, but I tried using `a3.5`, `b½`, and `cπ`, and the compiler said I was crazy.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, in `a3.5` you are trying to use `5` as member variable name, and since it starts with a number, it is not valid identifier name. And the other two are not valid numbers in Java, as reported by the ultimate authority in the matter, `javac` (just try `float f = ½;` or `float f = π;`) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As long as variable names are meaningful, using digits as part of the name is definitely not a bad thing. Of course, having a large number of similarly named variables with just a number at the end to differentiate them could be a sign of bad design.

The reason for nor allowing identifiers starting with digits, I'm pretty sure, is that it makes it so much easier to write the parser:

```
c = getchar(); 
ungetc(c);
if (isdigit(c)) 
   token = number(); 
else 
   token = identifier();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the rule off identifier that it must start with an letter or an underscore after that only digits are allowed.

Comment: This is stated incorrectly.  *"... after that only digits are allowed"* means (in English) that only the first character can be a letter or underscore.  That is plainly incorrect.